# Laravel Entrust return auth user with roles

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with Laravel and Entrust and the basics work fine. I do have one issue that doesnt seem to come with the package. What I would like is when I do `Auth::user()` if they are logged in it returns their Roles as well. Currently I know I can do `Auth::user()->roles`, but for that to work I need to check if they are a user first. I would image there is an easier way and convenient, for when you return the auth user you get there roles as well.

Here is how I currently set up the head.blade.php file

```
<?php if( Auth::user() ){ $roles = Auth::user()->roles()->get(); }else{$roles = null;} ?>

<!-- global config -->
<script>

    window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        'stripeKey'=> config('services.stripe.key'),
        'user'=> Auth::user(),
        'roles' => $roles,

    ]) !!};

</script>
```

It would be a lot simpler to not even need the roles object but access through `window.Laravel.user.roles`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the `load` method:

```
'user'=> Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->load('roles') : null,
```

However you'll probably -depends what you need- have some unwanted properties with this approach, like the pivot table properties.

It might be better to make a `user` property created in the controller and passed to the view containing the information you need.